# Pod Resources Monitoring

Tags: resources, kubernetes, monitoring

In kubernetes, we can specify the the resources required with some upper limit in terms of their capacity(like memory(primary memory), CPU etc). But, is there any way to specify how much of secondary memory can be allocated to a particular pod? I understand secondary memory can be allocated externally by Volumes. But otherwise, how much secondary memory does a pod have and how can we vary it?

Answer (score 2):

Pod resource allocation above the resource requests you define for a container (assuming you are not defining limits) is taken from whatever is available on the host the pod was deployed to by the scheduler.

This means that it will depend on:

1. What size instance it's deployed on
2. what else is running on that node
3. How much unallocated resources are left afterwards